# Getting a 500 error when clicking the "Back to Index" button in my Google Apps Script web application

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a problem in my simple Grade Inquiries system which I want to create for my TA work.
I want to create a index.html for students enter their name&stdentId,then if there is the name&stdentId  which they input in the google.sheet that i connect with,jump to the result.html and print their grade.

Now, the problem is when I enter the correct name&stdentId,it can jump to  the result.html,but when i click
thegoBack button it show "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()".

If you can help me i will be really thankful.
thanks :)

here is part of my Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  let html;
  
  if (e.parameter.page === 'toResult') {
    // 如果參數為 'toResult'，則進行跳轉至 result.html
    let studentId = e.parameter.studentId;
    let htmlOutPut = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('result');
    htmlOutPut.studentId = studentId;
    let check = htmlOutPut.evaluate();
    check.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  return check;
  } 
  else if (e.parameter.page === 'goBack') {
    // 如果參數為 'goBack'，則渲染 index.html
    let htmlOutPut = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
    let check = htmlOutPut.evaluate();
    check.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  return check;
  } 
  else {
    // 預設情況下，渲染 index.html
    let htmlOutPut = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
    let check= htmlOutPut.evaluate();
    check.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    return check;
  } 
}


function getUrl(){
  let url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}

function isTrueStudent(name, studentId) {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName("匯總");
  let range = sheet.getRange("A10:B71");
  let values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] === studentId && values[i][1] === name) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

and here is part of my result.html

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <?let url = getUrl();?><input type="hidden" value="<?= url ?>" id="url"/>
      <h1>查詢结果</h1>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th class="gradeName">點名成績10%</th>
          <td class="gradeData" id="Grade E"></th>
        </tr>
        <!-- ...skip -->
        <tr>
          <th class="gradeName">期中考</th>
          <td class="gradeData" id="Grade F"></th>
       
      </table>

      <div class="button-container">
        <button onclick="goBack()">返回</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
       function goBack() {
        let url = document.getElementById("url").value;
        let link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url + "&page=goBack";
        link.id = 'linkURL';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        document.getElementById('linkURL').click();
      }
    </script>
```

i want to redirct to index.html when I click the goBack button on result.html.
ive several tried by asking ChatGpt but still cannot solve the problem.

Comment: `ive several tried by asking ChatGpt but still cannot solve the problem.` ChatGPT is (currently) notoriously unreliable and not worth the time or effort.